# What is the use of Annotation "@FindBy"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, annotations, webdriver, findby

Can anyone explain me about Annotation `@FindBy` in `WebDriver`?

Where and why it is used?

Answer (score 16):

It's to assist with the construction of locators when using the Page Factory to support your Page Objects

[PageFactory Wiki Page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)

However I'm discovering that I find it more useful to store your locators as By objects rather than WebElements as they are more flexible and you tend to avoid running into the StaleElementException.

```
By myLocator = By.id("idOfYourElement")
```

instead of

```
@FindBy(id = "idOfYourElement")
WebElement myLocator;
```

This way you can also use your locators when asserting the absence of an element or use it in the ExpectedConditions helpers.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why anyone would use @FindBy  instead of By objects.

Comment: @elroso Can I use PageFactory.initElements(driver, page) method when removing the annotations?  Thanks

Comment: Good explanation of using By rather than @FindBy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Can I cite [API-documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)?

> Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate an **alternative mechanism for locating the element** or a list of elements. Used in conjunction with `PageFactory#proxyElement` this allows users to quickly and easily create PageObjects.

So, if you use `PageObject` pattern then you adds this annotation to class members and `WebDriver` automatically inject appropriate `WebElement`s to it during object initialization (when `PageFactory.initElements()` called).

I strongly recommend to follow this link and read about [`PageObject` pattern and `@FindBy` annotations usage](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) with more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, i have another question...will it be used for elements changing their locators dynamically?

Comment: @user1163375 Whats you mean by saying `changing their locators dynamically`?

Comment: What my understanding is "@FindBy" Annotation is used when elements ID's are changing dynamically in web application....Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: `@FindBy` is used for getting access to element at web page with known id/name/etc If element's ID created automatically then how WebDriver will know about it?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin : could you please update the links, they are broken it seems. Would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Pagefactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory), and have something like:

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "logonName")
private WebElement logonNameField;

@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "password")
private WebElement passwordField;
```

Now, as for How., you can have:

1. CLASS_NAME
2. CSS
3. ID
4. ID_OR_NAME
5. LINK_TEXT
6. NAME
7. PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT
8. TAG_NAME
9. XPATH
10. class

Or you can use your own DOM Search plus Xpath, that would be outside of WebDriver API , but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of PageFactory class, we use annotations `@FindBy` to find WebElements. We use initElements method to initialize web elements. `@FindBy` can accept tagName, partialLinkText, name, linkText, id, css, className, xpath as attributes.

The `@FindBy` annotation locates one or more WebElements using a single criterion. For example, to identify all elements that have the same class attribute, we could use the following identification:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "classname")
private List<WebElement> singlecriterion;`enter code here`
```

Comment: format code names like **@FindBy** within answer properly with `` or ctrl+k