# @Findby using xpath with index

Tags: java, selenium, testng, findby

Can I use @Findby and pass certain values as parameter?

```
@FindBy("//div[contains(@class,'gallery_grid_image_caption gallery_grid_image_caption_padding')]"[$INDEX])
```

I know I can do this while using findElement. Kindly let me know if there is a solution/work around.

What I want to do it is let's say there is a for loop and there is a list of elements in a page. Now let's say the only thing that is changing among these fields is the bit of the xpath. `//div/1`, `//div/2` .... What I want to do is represent one element for all these elements and pass the ending values as parameter.

Comment: Can you tell me which language r u using????

Comment: @PrakashP : does the answer help?

Comment: @nullpointer No. My question is different. What I want to do it is let's say there is a for loop and there is a list of elements in a page. Now let's say the only thing that is changing among these fields is the bit of the xpath. `//div/1`, `//div/2` .... What I want to do is represent one element for all these elements and pass the ending values as parameter.

Comment: @PrakashP : instead could you please add this explanation to the question and update

Comment: @nullpointer I did that. As of now I have a taken a different approach using driver.findelement

Comment: @nullpointer Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: could you update an answer here

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are trying to do is something like this :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'gallery_grid_image_caption gallery_grid_image_caption_padding')]")
public WebElement yourElement;
```

[SO-9028757](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028757/what-is-the-use-of-annotation-findby) should provide you more context.