# How does Selenium Annotation "@FindBy" work when it returns no element?

Tags: selenium, findby

If @FindBy returns no element, do we get error as I saw @FindBy could be used to get 0 to multiple elements.

Scenario:
@FindBy(id = "btn")
private WebElement searchButton;  //allows single element to be referenced

Case 1: If we have no elements having id as "btn", then what would be the result?
Case 2: If we have multiple elements having id as "btn",then  what would be the result?

Please clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of Annotation "@FindBy"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028757/what-is-the-use-of-annotation-findby)

Answer (score 0):

You won't receive an error when calling `PageFactory.initElements`, element that wasn't found will be set to `null`. However you will get `NullPointerException` when you try to use the element.

Answer (score 0):

> Case 1: If we have no elements having id as "btn", then what would be the result?

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"<invalid name>"}
```

> Case 2: If we have multiple elements having id as "btn",then what would be the result?

Since we have multiple elements, we could not do any actions due to ambiguity.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

Comment: Please don't publish answer to a question through multiple parts. Instead publish your self answer within a single answer space.

Comment: I have updated this answer with the second part of your answer.